# Python nose framework: How to stop execution upon first failure

Tags: python, unit-testing

It seems that if a testcase fails, nose will attempt to execute the next testcases. How can I  make nose  to abort all execution upon the first error in any testcase? I tried sys.exit() but it gave me some ugly and lengthy messages about it

Comment: Just for reference, for debugging in PyCharm, there is an open issue about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9848

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is an option for nose:

```
-x, --stop
Stop running tests after the first error or failure
```

Is this what you need?

Following link can help you with all the options available for nosetests.
    http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: Yes, Thanks! and while we are on it how do I:
1. Prevent printing the ugly stack trace upon failure?
2. Exit the current test suite upon failure but continue executing the rest of them

Comment: I don't really use nose :-), I was just pretty sure it must have fail fast option (just django test framework has), so I took a look at nose options: http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/usage.html#options

Comment: Those sound like separate questions.  You might check [this question for reducing the amount of information printed by nose](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11425947/1309332).  I haven't seen anything about exiting after a suite.