# nosetest - get list of failed tests (without extra output)

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

Is it possible to have nose output only the *name* of the tests that fail to get a simple and compact list of failed tests?

I have figured out how to discard the captured stdout:

```
nosetests -s
```

but the assertion that fails is still printed (for example, assertEqual prints both the expected & actual values).  Ideally I just want to know the file and line that failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425947/how-can-you-suppress-traces-for-failed-test-cases-using-nose/13928546#13928546 is a very similar question.

Answer (score 1):

A very quick and primitive answer to your issue:

If you use ***--verbosity=2***  parameter, it will list out all your tests

If you redirect stderr to stdout you can get a text file, something like this (example below would be run inside ***tests*** folder):

`nosetests -s --verbosity=2 test_tasks.py > mytestresults.txt 2>&1`

This will create a full list of all your tests and whether they pass or fail at the top of `mytestresults.txt` (you can trim off all the Assertion outputs, trace, etc. for failed tests after you get the list of tests from the top of `mytestresults.txt`).

### Sample output below:

```
test_admin_users_can_complete_tasks_that_are_not_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... ok

test_admin_users_can_delete_tasks_that_are_not_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... ok

test_admin_users_can_see_task_modify_links_for_all_tasks (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_logged_in_users_can_access_tasks_page (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_not_logged_in_users_cannot_access_tasks_page (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... ok

test_string_representation_of_the_task_object (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... ERROR

test_task_template_displays_logged_in_user_name (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_can_add_tasks (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_can_complete_tasks (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_can_delete_tasks (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_can_see_task_modify_links_for_tasks_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_cannot_add_tasks_when_error (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_cannot_complete_tasks_that_are_not_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_cannot_delete_tasks_that_are_not_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... FAIL

test_users_cannot_see_task_modify_links_for_tasks_not_created_by_them (tests.test_tasks.TasksTests) ... ok

... stack trace, etc. will be down here (not shown for brevity) ...
```

---

EDIT: oops I wrote this, saved, then noticed that you wanted the line number also. You would have to parse this out of the trace detail or a much more ***refined*** approach would be to use [Nose-progressive plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-progressive/)
 to format the output whatever way you like.